# Set a gap between the beginning of the JLabel and the icon

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a Java Swing form and JLabel like this:

[image]

What I need to do is inserting a gap in the beginning of the JLabel:

[image]

So it will not stuck to the border line.

Note 1 : I already used `jLabName.setIconTextGap(35);` but it did the below:

[image]

I need to insert the gap before the icon not after it!

Note 2 : The Border Setting And Type And other setting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [compound borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html) for that.

For Example.

```
//get border of your component which is button as you say
Border border = myButton.getBorder();

//create a new empty border with name it margin
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0); //top 0, left 10 , bottom 0, right 0

//now set compound border to your button(component), with margin
myButton.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));

//NOTE: CompoundBorder accepts two borders as arguments, first one is inner border and last one is outer border
```

Comment: (1+) good solution for a JButton. However, the OP has updated the question to indicate that they are indeed using a JLabel. Since a JLabel doesn't have a default Border there is no need for the logic to get the original border.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following code:

```
a1.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EtchedBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 8, 1, 1)));
```